# javac -Xlint:overrides not working

Tags: java, ant, javac

I'm trying to get my java build to fail when I have a class that overrides a superclass method without specifying the @Override annotation.

The build is being done via ant, and I've added the following elements to my `<javac>` task:

```
<compilerarg value="-Werror"/>
<compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked,overrides"/>
```

The `unchecked` option is being followed, but the `overrides` option is being ignored.  I also tried separating the two `Xlint` options into two separate `<compilerarg>` elements, to no avail.  Am I misunderstanding what this option does?

One note: this is JDK6 on MacOSX (10.6).  Could I be running into a OSX-specific bug?

Comment: Works fine on my OS X machine.  I tested with the override example here: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/5276 javac 1.6.0_22

Comment: If you use IntelliJ IDEA it has an inspection for doing exactly this, but it isn't enabled by default, you can go to settings > inspections > Missing Override Annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the `Xlint:overrides` behaviour.

To my knowledge, enabling this check will cause the compiler to emit warnings (or maybe errors) when it encounters a method annotated with `@Override` that does not actually override a superclass method. It does not, however, check that all overridden methods are annotated correctly.

EDIT: Just tested it. The compiler will emit an error when you specify `@Override` on a method that does not override a superclass method, with or without the `Xlint` option.

The documentation on [Oracle's website](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) doesn't even mention the Xlint:overrides option so I'm guessing it's not implemented.

Comment: Thanks, that answers that question.  Now I just need to figure out how to make my build fail when @Override is absent on an overridden method...

Comment: I believe it might be possible to tell Findbugs or Checkstyle to fail on this kind of error...I only vaguely remember, so I could be wrong. There's bound to be a tool somewhere that does it :)

Comment: @CameronSkinner I just looked at Findbugs and Checkstyle and neither had such a check. Checkstyle has a MissingOverride check but it only "Verifies that the java.lang.Override annotation is present when the {@inheritDoc} javadoc tag is present", so it doesn't work if you forgot the documentation too.

Answer (score 1):

Xlint:overrides is more subtle than @Override.  @Override (as Cameron Skinner points out) will cause an error to be emitted by the compiler if it annotates a method which does not in fact override another method.  The Xlint:overrides option, however, produces a warning if one has marked a method with a varargs parameter to override another which doesn't have a varargs parameter but instead uses an array.  A good explanation is found here:

http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2010/10/javacs-xlint-options.html